# Using Vectors to find direction of travel against force

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, physics

I'm working my way through some multivariable calculus using the 4th edition of the Hughes-Hallett text Single and Multivariable Calculus.

I'm having trouble with one of the questions - I cannot figure out how the answer the book gives is obtained. I suspect I'm thinking about the mechanics of the problem incorrectly. The book seems to assume some elementary knowledge of physics that I do not have.

Here is the problem:

> A man wishes to row the shortest possible distance from north to south across a river which is flowing at 4 km/hr from the east. He can row at 5 km/hr. If there is a wind of 10 km/hr from the southwest, in which direction should he steer to try and go directly across the river? What happens?

The problem is in the review section of the first chapter on Vectors, and the chapter gives minimal information about forces.

If I let $\vec{w}$ be the velocity vector for the wind, then I have $\vec{w} = 5\sqrt2\ \vec{i}+5\sqrt2\ \vec{j}$. If I let $\vec{c}$ be the velocity vector for the current, I have $\vec{c}=-4\ \vec{i}$

My idea for a solution was to add $\vec{w}+\vec{c}$ to get the combined velocity vector of the current and wind. This would be the direction the boat would be carried if the man was not steering at all.  Then I would have to find a new vector $\vec{v}$ so that $\vec{v}+\vec{w}+\vec{c}=-\vec{j}$, or perhaps some scalar multiple of j? I'm really not sure. The book doesn't expand much on how to deal with the magnitudes.

In any event, this method doesn't not give me the answer the book has. I get $\vec{v}=-3.07\vec{i}+-8.071\vec{j}$, which gives that the angle the man should steer is 20.8 degree west of south. But the book answer is 37.9 degrees west of south. The book also says if he steers in this direction, the boat will not move.

Any help or thoughts on this problem would be helpful. I've been thinking about it for so long - it seems like it should be simple so I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: Your idea is sound. Perhaps if you show us your work we can find the mistake.

Comment: Note that the $\vec v$ you computed has a magnitude greater than $5,$ so it does not represent the man rowing at $5$ km/hr in any particular direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the forces of the stream and the wind correct (although it's hard to believe they want you to give them equal weight, but whatever ...)  The problem is with the rowing.

The rower will row with some velocity  $a\vec{i}+b\vec{j}$  He wants to row straight across the stream, so
$v_i + w_i + a_i = 0$.

We still need a condition on $b$.  We are told that he can row 5 km/hr.  Therefore

$a^2 + b^2 = 25$.

With those two equations, you should be able to solve the problem.

Comment: Ah - I see now. My mistake was in not making sure the vector of the direction the man rows had a magnitude of 5. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the idea would be to balance out the horizontal component. Wind contributes $5 \sqrt{2}$ and current $-4$, and with his contribution it should be $0$.

The problem here is that the wind also contributes $5\sqrt{2}$ against his movement, and he can only row at $5$ km/hr, which is less than the wind, so the best he can hope for is to avoid horizontal drift and the boat not to move at all...

Comment: And the boat presumably would be blown northward (opposite the desired direction) if there were not a shoreline preventing it from moving in that direction. But what would happen if the man did not row at all? Would the boat scrape along the shoreline at $3.07$ km/hr, or would it be stuck in place? It seems an ill-posed question altogether, even aside from the highly unrealistic treatment of wind effect on a rowboat.